# SQL Joins to use aggregate functions on same column with multiple tables

Tags: sql

How to create a single query from below queries, i tried but no luck.

```
SELECT concat(TITLE,' ',NAME,' ',SUR_NAME) AS Client, 
FROM CLIENT

SELECT CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(DISPLAY_BALANCE) AS X_AGG
FROM CLIENT_ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE IN ('XLOAN','YLOAN')
GROUP BY CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER

SELECT CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(DISPLAY_BALANCE) AS Y_AGG
FROM CLIENT_ACCOUNT CA LEFT JOIN  ACCOUNT_TYPE at 
ON ca.ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE = at.ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE
WHERE TRANSACTIONAL= 1
GROUP BY CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

At the end i am also expecting one column which will be difference of X_AGG & Y_AGG.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Combine how? Show us sample result from each query, and also the combined result. And table data too. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: What table does `TRANSACTIONAL`  belong to? You should qualify all columns with the table alias for easier reading.

Comment: aliases does not always makes it eazier @WEI_DBA what if you have two name names `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER` and `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NOTES` for example how would you alias it? You can't use `CAN` for easy reading and understanding and using `CANU` and `CANO` also reads a bit wierd and what are you going to use if you also have a `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NOTEBOOK` table .. Also some database explain plan (like MySQL) tends to show the alias name in the output which makes optimizing also harder.. Because you need to backtrack which alias is which table.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Ganesh is there any foreign key between CLIENT  and CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER based on which we can use join ? idea is simple here we can put left join in first two tables and then on result set we can place another left join between last table and subquery result table

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I'm just trying to figure out what table `Transactional` belongs to in the bottom query. If it belongs to `Account_Type`, then that would make it an inner join instead of a left join. Not that it won't make a difference most likely, but just trying to help out here. Didn't think I'd get slammed for that question.

Comment: Well @WEI_DBA it was not meant as slamming... You are right that you want to know in which table the column `TRANSACTIONAL` belongs. if it the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` table the `WHERE`  filter should indeed be in the `ON` clause or the question is if `LEFT JOIN` query should be converted to a `INNER JOIN`.. But the topicstarter would need to provide example data and expected results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland i'd use `CANUM` for `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER`, `CANOT` for `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NOTES` and `CANTB` for `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_NOTEBOOK`. Of course if there are other `*_NUMBER` `*_NOTES` and `*_NOTEBOOK` tables in the query, otherwise I'd use `NUMBER` `NOTES` and `NOTEBOOK` respectively, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: i know you can use that @reportgunner the main "problem" is that explain plan on some database system can show aliases only that meant you need to backtrack the alias in the explain output to your query..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Thanks for clarification! Agreed, sample data and expected output would help immensely. Even table schemas would be great as well.